# Why doesn't this make sense? Removing Nodes

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I have code that takes user input and increments a counter for printing and deleting purposes. I added some print lines to see what the count difference was between the linked list and the current position and this is what I got:

```
Enter a command from the list above (q to quit): 
2
Deleted: e                e                5                $5.0
 Current record is now first record.
4
5
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
        at java.util.LinkedList.entry(LinkedList.java:365)
        at java.util.LinkedList.get(LinkedList.java:315)
        at bankdata.command(bankdata.java:158)
        at bankdata.main(bankdata.java:314)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 18 seconds)
```

enter command 2, the remove current node command. The current node is the last in the linked list which is 5 in size which technically means from 0-4.

SO how come when I run this code:

```
//currentAccount is a static int that was created at the start of my code.
//It got it's size because the int is saved every time a new node is made.
//The most recent size correlates with the last position in the linked list.
            int altefucseyegiv = accountRecords.size();
            System.out.println("Deleted: " + accountRecords.get(currentAccount)
                    + "\n Current record is now first record.");
            System.out.println(currentAccount);
            System.out.println(accountRecords.size());
            accountRecords.remove(currentAccount);
            System.out.println("Deleted: " + accountRecords.get(currentAccount)
                    + "\n Current record is now first record.");
            if(altefucseyegiv == 1)
            {
                currentAccount = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                currentAccount = 0;
            }
            records.currentAcc(currentAccount, accountRecords);
            return;
```

I get this error???

I'm confused! Because I'm removing the .get(4)th and that means I'm just removing the 5th element and I don't mean love. Can someone explain and possibly help me fix this please?

Comment: Yes you can access this element when you print indices. But then you're calling: `accountRecords.remove(currentAccount);`. Try to output current index and size after remove maybe that will help to understand the problem.

Comment: I used a catch to check this exception and I still have the same sizes :/

Comment: on top of that if I decrease the currentAccount size by one then it deletes not the last node, but the one right before the last node, yet it won't delete the last node.

Comment: @RyanTibbets Show us exception handling code. Or just surround the line (only one line) that throws exception with `try..catch` and output size and index in catch.

Comment: Can you also share how `currentAccount` is initialized

Comment: The question was already answered. But I can indeed add these informations for future incidents of people missing this simple error. Just quickly though, the currentAccount is a static int that = -1 originally but is matched up with the position of the current node I look at for editing in my program. The full code can be seen here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679399/i-made-this-program-and-it-prints-one-extra-thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Object obj = accountRecords.remove(currentAccount);
System.out.println("Deleted: " + obj + "\n Current record is now first record.");
```

I'm assuming you have initialized `currentAccount` as `accountRecords.size() - 1` and `accountRecords` has 5 nodes.

Then `currentAccount` has a value 4 and you are removing 4th element from the list leaving `accountRecords` with only 4 elements.

Then you are trying to fetch `accountRecords.get(4)` from the list where `accountRecords` has only 4 elements and the valid element indexes are `0..3`, that is why you are getting the error.

Comment: This is conditional, but if you know what a Darlek is then I would read this in their voice: EXPLAIN! EXPLAAAAAIN!

Answer (score 4):

The IOFB Exception is thrown by the line

```
System.out.println("Deleted: " + accountRecords.get(currentAccount)
                + "\n Current record is now first record.");
```

You have removed the 5th element, so now there is no 5th element to show (remember array positions start on 0)

Comment: Oic. OH IC! Well! That was something I bet I'da noticed if I were more awake XD Thanks haha!

Answer (score 1):

i think your mistake is your println:

```
System.out.println("Deleted: " + accountRecords.get(currentAccount)
                + "\n Current record is now first record.");
```

<- you get the IndexOutOfBoundsException because you deleted the last entry of the list, or i am wrong? 
maybe try:
    System.out.println("Deleted: " + accountRecords.get(currentAccount-1)
                    + "\n Current record is now first record.");

Comment: Linked lists don't have a null end value like arrays do I don't think. They have null connectors, but not full null nodes sitting at the end. Only thing I know of like that is the head dud.